# Not able to create my first Vagrant Image

Tags: ruby, vagrant, virtualbox

I am trying setup centos65 vegrant image to setup my ruby test kitchen. But I am not able to create with following error:

```
c:\opscode\chefdk\bin\kitchen create default-centos65
-----> Starting Kitchen (v1.4.0)
-----> Creating <default-centos65>...
       Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
       ==> default: Checking if box 'learningchef/centos65' is up to date...
       ==> default: There was a problem while downloading the metadata for your box
       ==> default: to check for updates. This is not an error, since it is usually due
       ==> default: to temporary network problems. This is just a warning. The problem
       ==> default: encountered was:
       ==> default:
       ==> default: Could not resolve host: (nil); Host not found
       ==> default:
       ==> default: If you want to check for box updates, verify your network connection
       ==> default: is valid and try again.
       ==> default: VirtualBox VM is already running.
       Waiting for SSH service on 127.0.0.1:2201, retrying in 3 seconds
       Waiting for SSH service on 127.0.0.1:2201, retrying in 3 seconds
```

Any idea what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

you get the message :

```
=> default: VirtualBox VM is already running
```

so it has already been created. you should be able to verify and have something similar to

```
$ kitchen list
Instance             Driver   Provisioner  Last Action
default-centos65     Vagrant  ChefSolo     Created
```

and you should be able to run

```
$ kitchen login
```

to review things in your VM

Comment: I don't think it's created.Because when I ran the command:
$ c:\opscode\chefdk\embedded\bin\kitchen list
Instance          Driver   Provisioner  Verifier  Transport  Last Action
default-centos65  Vagrant  ChefSolo     Busser    Ssh        <Not Created>